# How to introduce custom environment variables to Debian package maintainer scripts (prerm, postrm, preinst, postinst)

Tags: linux, bash, debian, deb

I have a simple question, how do I introduce custom environment variables defined in my build configuration (e.g. CMake) to Debian package maintainer scripts (`prerm`, `postrm`, `preinst`, `postinst`) when building custom Debian packages?

Example: I have a variable called `CUSTOM_INSTALL_PATH = "/my/own/path"` from CMake and want to put it to all of the scripts so I can use it like

```
bash_variable=$CUSTOM_INSTALL_PATH
```

I tried looking up the documentation and didn't find anything of relevance.

Comment: Interesting question indeed but wrong forum!  Stack Overflow! [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean. Where should this variable come from? If it's known at build time, simply substitute it into the scripts where you need it.

Comment: If the value is supposed to be user-configurable, it should almost certainly go in the Debconf database.

Comment: @Jetchisel I am sorry, is there a way to migrate this question to Unix & Linux? Also tripleee, yeah I know spaces around equals sign are not valid, wrote that in a hurry. The value is not supposed to be user-configurable, but used for different build configurations (testing, etc..)

Comment: _and want to put it to all of the scripts_ : Are these scripts executed as child processes of CMake?

Comment: No, they are executed as standard part of debian package installation process (e.g. `sudo apt install ./my-package.deb`)

Comment: I don't agree that this needs to be migrated. If you really wanted to, you could flag for moderator attention and request migration, but then without more details this would probably be close-voted at the destination too, so please [edit] to clarify before doing anything like that.

Comment: So if the scripts and the make files are completely unrelated, how can the scripts know which of the makefile it should pick up the variable from? You **could** write a make target which writes the variable definitions to some file, and then in your bash script invoke cmake with this target and then reads the definitions; but this sounds so cumbersome, that perhaps you better rethink your workflow. Maybe you can have somewhere a configuration file holding those variable definition, and which is processed by both, bash and cmake. As tripleee said: It's unclear what you mean here.

Answer (score 0):

A simple mechanism is to have `cmake` drop the value somewhere, and have your scripts source that file.

For example, suppose `/etc/yourpackage_path.cfg` is created with the contents

```
/my/own/path
```

then you can create a `preinst` like

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

read -r bash_variable </etc/yourpackage_path.cfg
: use "$bash_variable" to your heart's content here
```

and similarly for other files in the package.

(Technically you could also generate the scripts from your `debian/rules` and inline the value at build time; but making them static seems more robust and predictable.)

Notice that files in `/etc` should be user-editable configuration files; perhaps a static file in `/usr/share/lib/yourpackage` or etc would make more sense, depending on your precise use case.